# attrs invisible with more than 2 arguments or with !=

Tags: python, xml, odoo

here is my source code and 
i need to know hide **bank_id** field when i select != bank value from selection box ?
I tried with

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('special_deduction_type', '!=', 'bank')]}"
```

also for all fields.but then many2one fields shows in out of layout.please refer the image

```
![<page string="Special Deductions">
<field name='special_deduction_ids' nolabel='1'>
<tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
<field name='deduction_id' invisible="1" />
<field name='special_deduction_type' />
<field name='bank_id'
attrs="{'invisible': \[('special_deduction_type', '=', 'bank')\]}" />
<field name='union_id'
attrs="{'invisible': \[('special_deduction_type', '=', 'union')\]}" />
<field name='insurance_id'
attrs="{'invisible': \[('special_deduction_type', '=', 'insurance')\]}" />
<field name='loan_id'
attrs="{'invisible': \[('special_deduction_type', '=', 'loan')\]}" />
</tree>
</field>]
```

[image]

Comment: Please correct your sentencing, it's hard to understand what it is you're trying to acomplish.. something about a selection box? **how** and **where** do you want to hide the `bank*` value? in the webpage? or in the backend?
Is it a string or a map or a list that you've stored the field values?

Comment: Its not clear what are trying to do?

Comment: @user1576199
thanks friend..need to add 'in' there :-)
now its sorted..wt abt landed cost issue.?

Comment: not get time to test friend!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<page string="Special Deductions">
<field name='special_deduction_ids' nolabel='1'>
<tree string='List' editable='bottom'>
<field name='deduction_id' invisible="1" />
<field name='special_deduction_type' />
<field name='bank_id'
attrs="{'invisible': [('special_deduction_type','in',('loan','union','insurance'))]}"/>
<field name='union_id'
attrs="{'invisible': [('special_deduction_type','in',('bank','loan','insurance'))]}"/>
<field name='insurance_id'
attrs="{'invisible': [('special_deduction_type','in',('loan','union','bank'))]}"/>
<field name='loan_id'
attrs="{'invisible': [('special_deduction_type','in',('bank','union','insurance'))]}"/>

</tree>
</field>
<br />
<br />
</page>
```